# Wordpress can't upload media saying "no permission"

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I just setup a wordpress + nginx, but when I start to write my first blog, there comes a trouble. In admin page, I try to add a picture into media library, it complains "can't create wp-content/uploads/2015/05, permission denied".

Although I search the internet, most of guys are pointing to change ownershipt of "wp-contents/uploads" to be as php-fpm. But yes, I have checked the permission of uploads and also the running user of php-fpm. The worker php-fpm is running under "nginx" user, and namei for uploads:

```
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root var
drwxr-xr-x root root blog
drwxrwxrwx nginx nginx wp-content
drwxrwxrwx nginx nginx uploads
```

Then I use auditctl to check the activity on this "uploads" folder and see :

============================

```
type=PATH msg=audit(05/08/2015 14:07:00.247:1913) : item=1 name=/var/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015 objtype=CREATE
type=PATH msg=audit(05/08/2015 14:07:00.247:1913) : item=0 name=/var/blog/wp-content/uploads/ inode=266 dev=fd:01 mode=dir,777 ouid=nginx ogid=nginx rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 objtype=PARENT
type=CWD msg=audit(05/08/2015 14:07:00.247:1913) : cwd=/var/blog/wp-admin
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(05/08/2015 14:07:00.247:1913) : arch=x86_64 syscall=mkdir success=no exit=-13(Permission denied) a0=0x7fff691d28c0 a1=0777 a2=0x8 a3=0x6e65746e6f632d70 items=2 ppid=13235 pid=13239 auid=unset uid=nginx gid=nginx euid=nginx suid=nginx
fsuid=nginx egid=nginx sgid=nginx fsgid=nginx tty=(none) ses=unset comm=php-fpm exe=/usr/sbin/php-fpm subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

=====================

So, what is the wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you make also sub folders of wp-uploads with the same permissions?

Comment: Yes, I used to create the sub directory manually with the same permission, in this case, that is, "2015"and "05" under uploads. Then, the error from WordPress is turned into "can't move" the file into uploads/2015/05, the same reason "permission denied".